# Need Formula: Conditional Formatting Using countif and drop down menu

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I want to add/subtract two values in two different cell as per drop down option.

For eg: If "Buy" is selected from drop down then subtract total price i.e G2 from credit balance H1 and mention the result in below cell of above credit balance i.e H2. OR if "sold" is selected from drop down then add total price i.e G3 to credit balance i.e H2 and placed the result in H3.

Thanks

[Cell Placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i94E.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are there other options in conditional options except "Buy" and "Sold"?

Maybe you could enter the formula "`=IF(C3="Buy",H2-G3,IF(C3="Sold",H2+G3,H2))`" in **H3**, and pull down.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help Emily, for now there will be only two options i.e buy & sold. But the above formula is not working with "Buy" option. It just pasting the above H cell value. Thanks!!

Comment: @Anmol Dhodhi, I add a gif to show the formula. The data in H2 is preset. When there is no option for C7, H7 will paste data from H6. When C5 is "Buy", H5 will get the data that subtract G5 from H4.